# JavaFx TreeTableCell's ComboBox body style

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

How can I style a `ComboBox` "body" part not the dropdown?

As you can see on the screenshot I want to style just that part where you click and opens the dropdown and the dropdown should remain as it is.

If I try for example:

```
.combo-box-base .list-cell{
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

everything goes red not just what I want.

I had a look at this question: [Javafx combobox styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343531/javafx-combobox-styling)
but it didnt really helped me, it styles everything but not that specific part I need.

I have also looked with ScenicView, and I could locate it and add as style: `-fx-background-color: red` and it worked, but from code I could't manage it.
In ScenicView I saw the ComboBox has three components:
a `StackPane` a `ListView` and a `ListCell`. I want to style just the `ListCell` part.

[image]

Here is how it looks like if I add those line in `my.css`:
As you can see I don't want the dropdown to be styled.

[image]

How can I solve it.

Note: the arrow should remain as it is, just that part where the text is shown, as the second screenshot shows.

Comment: Try `.combo-box > .list-cell { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: @Slaw yeah, you were quicker :) Indeed, you need a child combinator - though I'm slightly astonished that the descendent relationships holds for the dropdown ..

Comment: @kleopatra Not completely sure how it works, but the default skin of the `ComboBox` creates an anonymous `PopupControl` that overrides `getStyleableParent`, returning the `ComboBox`. Specifically, this happens in the `ComboBoxPopupControl` class.

Comment: @Slaw good point - thanks :)

Comment: @Slaw it worked, thanks ;)